# lateinit property apiInterface has not been initialized kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException:?

Tags: android, unit-testing, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I am  writing unit test for my viewmodel when I run test I am getting following exception

```
lateinit property apiInterface has not been initialized
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property apiInterface has not been initialized
    at com.yodgorbek.newstask.presentation.viewmodel.BBCNewsViewModelTest.setUp(BBCNewsViewModelTest.kt:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.interna
```

below my BBCNewsViewModelTest.kt where I am getting an exception

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class BBCNewsViewModelTest{
    private var progressObserver = MutableLiveData(false)
    private lateinit var apiInterface : NewsInterface

    private lateinit var newsRepository: NewsRepository
    private lateinit var bbcNewsResponseUseCase: BBCNewsResponseUseCase
    private lateinit var viewModel: BBCNewsViewModel
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        newsRepository = NewsRepository(apiInterface)
        bbcNewsResponseUseCase = BBCNewsResponseUseCase(newsRepository)
        viewModel = BBCNewsViewModel(bbcNewsResponseUseCase)
    }

    @Test
    fun testsSaveSessionData() = runBlockingTest {
        assert(progressObserver.value == viewModel.progress.value)

    }

}
```

below my Interface class where I am calling get news function

```
interface NewsInterface {

    @GET(Constants.BBC_URL)
    suspend fun getNews(): NewsResponse


}
```

below BBCNewsViewModel.kt

```
  import android.os.Build
    import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
    import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
    import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
    import com.yodgorbek.newstask.model.NewsResponse
    import com.yodgorbek.newstask.domain.use_case.BBCNewsResponseUseCase
    import com.yodgorbek.newstask.domain.utils.fold
    import com.yodgorbek.newstask.domain.utils.parseDate
    
    import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
    import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
    import java.util.Comparator
    
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        class BBCNewsViewModel(private val useCase: BBCNewsResponseUseCase) : ViewModel() {
        
        
             var news= MutableLiveData<NewsResponse>()
            // Expose to the outside world
        
            // Expose to the outside world
            private val error = MutableLiveData<String>()
            var progress = MutableLiveData(false)
        
        init{
            getNews()
        }
        
            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            private fun getNews() {
                progress.postValue(true)
                viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    useCase.invoke()
                        .fold({ newsResponse ->
                            newsResponse.articles.sortedWith(Comparator.comparing{
                                it.publishedAt.parseDate()
                            })
                            news.postValue(newsResponse)
        
                        }, {
                            error.postValue(it.message)
                        })
                    progress.postValue(false)
                }
            }
        
        
        
        
        }
```

below my NewsRepository.kt

```
class NewsRepository(
   private val apiInterface:NewsInterface
){


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
suspend fun getNews() : Result<NewsResponse>{
   return try {
       val response = apiInterface.getNews()
      Result.Success(response)
   } catch (ex: Exception) {
      Result.Error(ex)
   }
}



}
```

below my NewsResponse.kt

```
data class NewsResponse(
    @SerializedName("articles")
    val articles: List<Article>,
    @SerializedName("status")
    val status: String,
    @SerializedName("totalResults")
    val totalResults: Int
)
```

I want to know where exactly I am making mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the exception, you are not initializing the `apiInterface`.

In normal cases `Retrofit` is responsible for creating the instance of  `NewsInterface`. But in case of testing, you will be responsible for passing the instance. For that, you can create the mock implementation.

```
class MockNewsInterface: NewsInterface{
  suspend fun getNews(): NewsResponse{
     return NewsResponse() // Pass dummy implementation 
  }
}
```

Just replace this in your code

```
newsRepository = NewsRepository(MockNewsInterface())
```

I would suggest to use Mockito or [Mockk.io](https://Mockk.io) library. This will help write the test cases easily and efficiently.

Comment: for dummy date what I can pass

Comment: Can you share NewsResponse class

Comment: I have added NewsResponse class to my post

Comment: Is this working now?

Comment: what do you think main problem

Answer (score 1):

As your exception says `lateinit property apiInterface has not been initialized`

the `apiInterface` in `BBCNewsViewModelTest` is not initialized

and in your `setUp()` method, you're initializing `newsRepository = NewsRepository(apiInterface)` while the `apiInterface` is not initialized yet

you can initialize your `apiInterface` while declaring without lateinit, or in the `setup()` or if youre using any Dependency Injection you can do field injection

since you're using retrofit this is how you'd have to initialize

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .build();

NewsInterface service = retrofit.create(NewsInterface.class);
```

Comment: how can I initialize using init can you eloborate your answer @PraveenG

Comment: if I wrote like this  apiInterface = NewsInterface in setup method  I am getting following message Classifier 'NewsInterface' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Comment: @PreveenG what is your suggestion

Comment: you cant initialize a interface that way, you need to create an Impl for that interface

Comment: I dont needimpl it is giving an error due to interface class mainly responsible for calling ending point

Comment: this is how I'd approach architecture-wise, this could help? https://proandroiddev.com/why-you-need-use-cases-interactors-142e8a6fe576

Comment: I checked but I want to know what exactly causing problem

Comment: how can Initailize interface in my viewmodel test

Comment: my question related to interface not architecture

Comment: are you using retrofit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242189/discussion-between-sashabeliy-and-praveen-g).